# USB Debugging setting keeps "unchecking"

Tags: android, debugging, usb

I'm doing Android development with Eclipse 3.6.2, OS X 10.6.7 and a Samsung Galaxy Tab.

Everything is working great, **except** every 15 or 20 minutes, the Settings | Applications | Development | USB debugging checkbox "unchecks" itself.  Which means I need to unplug the USB cable and go back into the setting, re-select the checkbox, plug the cable back in and I'm good to go.

What I would like to know is if there is some way to make that checkbox "sticky" (I asssume it probably is supposed to be - but I haven't been able to figure out under what circumstances cause the "uncheck" to occur).  I've tried a number of variations of USB / sdcard / Development settings and haven't found the "sticky bit" yet.

I'm new to Android, so I'm hoping there is some "you forgot to also do X" here...

EDIT:

Maybe it has to do with a USB Mass Storage message that pops up after 10 min or so?  I just noticed a message "USB Connected: You have connected your phone to your computer via USB.  Select Mount if you want to copy files between your computer and your phones SD card".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a Galaxy Tab and have not experienced this behavior. Nor have I encountered this on any other Android device, and I have used quite a few for development purposes.

From what I can tell, this state cannot be toggled via SDK applications, but only via the firmware. My guess is that there is something flaky in your setup that is triggering something in the Tab's firmware to do this.

Sorry that I don't have a silver bullet for you.

---

**UPDATE**

> Maybe it has to do with a USB Mass Storage message that pops up after 10 min or so? I just noticed a message "USB Connected: You have connected your phone to your computer via USB. Select Mount if you want to copy files between your computer and your phones SD card".

That further suggests there is something strange going on between your development machine and the Tab. That should appear when you first plug in the cable, then remain there until you unplug the cable. I would not expect it to be toggling the USB debugging checkbox, but I am really starting to think you have one screwed-up Tab.

Comment: Fair enough - one thing I hadn't thought of was to reset the device to the original state (I assume there is a "factory reset" option somewhere).  I'll try that.  Good to know it is "not normal".

Comment: @Eric: Normally the factory reset option is in the Settings app somewhere, though I seem to recall I had to do something else for the Tab (hold down something while powering the unit on).

Comment: Factory reset didn't work - I'll keep poking around, but if I can't figure it out this will be the answer I go with... :)

Comment: Thanks, Mark - I appreciate the info.  I guess I'll wander in to the Verizon store and see what they say.

Comment: I'm confused; is there a solution here? It's happening to me every few minutes. I'm seeing the same thing too, and this tab was recently given a full factory reset.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem on Huawei P20. Upon activating developer options, what I did was :

- On the smartphone, open System Settings -> Developer options -> Enable USB debugging
- Connect the smartphone to the computer
- When the prompt shows on the smartphone select "File Transfer"
- Uncheck and check USB debbuging (smartphone is still connected to computer)
- The prompt for USB debugging finally appears

Hope it helps.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Just followed this process and it fixed USB debugging on a OnePlus 8 Running Android 12.

Answer (score 2):

verizon has something running in the background making this happen and having the same problem on my samsung fascinate after upgrading to fro yo. I think they're trying to block usb tethering

Answer (score 0):

My Galaxy Tab 7" does this all the time.  I would be in the middle of something and it would just drop.  Over & over.

The solution that I found that works great for me is to just use adbWireless.  This allows you to run ADB over wifi instead of USB.  adbWireless can be found on the Android Market.  It does require you to ROOT your phone, but since you are developing for it, you will want to do that anyway.

Comment: You can also run ADB via WiFi without rooting the device. See this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp#comment11863644_3623727

Answer (score 0):

THis seems to have gone away in 2.3 for DroidX. But it was quite frustrating when I was using DroidX w/ 2.2 on OS X to debug.